# CUDA Debugging - VS on windows workstation, GPUs on Linux server?

Tags: cuda, remote-debugging

Has anyone had any experience debugging CUDA code on a server while coding on a workstation?

My laptop (Thinkpad T400) doesn't support CUDA, but I have access to a server with pair of NVIDIA GTX 295 cards that runs Linux.

Can I use NVidia's Visual Studio tools to debug remotely on the server?

Failing that, I also have an Ubuntu VM running on my laptop. Is there a debugger that I can use under Linux to debug on the server?

I really don't want to have to buy another laptop with dual NVidia cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developing in c on a remote linux machine (like your server) is quite common. You can ssh onto the server from any client (like your laptop) to compile and run the code just as you would if you were sitting at the machine, and you can use [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to debug your code in a terminal. You can also use [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) as a graphical front end to gdb or a linux IDE such as [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/) by forwarding X11 over ssh.

You can use [cuda-gdb](http://developer.nvidia.com/content/cuda-gdb) to debug your CUDA code in a terminal in exactly the same way. Unfortunately, there is not a visual cuda debugger for linux yet. However, it appears you can use ddd with cuda-gdb [[source]](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=87996), as you have two gpus. I'm not sure about [using cuda-gdb in eclipse](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=153283).

Comment: There are some commercial graphical debuggers available for Linux too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but you need to buy the [Parallel Nsight Studio from Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/object/parallel-nsight.html)
After installing on the remote machine the NsightDebugServer you can upload and debug programs from
your cuda-less laptop.

**Update**

Turns out This solution requires a WINDOWS server in order to run the NsightDebugServer.

To connect to the linux machine from your laptop, use a remote connection.
install putty and a Xserver for windows and just login with 
ssh -X username@cudaserver.
The environment would not be fancy as Visual Studio but you can do the basic steps of debugging.

Eclipse "might" have some support for remote gdb servers. Never experimented that (Emacs + gdb is sufficient for me)

Comment: I can't any mention of a debug server for Linux; am I missing something? Oh, and Parallel NSight pro is now free.

Comment: As far as I remember there is a linux server component for Nsight parallel studio. Most of the setups are linux anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing anything like that. Everything I've read says that Parallel Nsight is exclusively for Windows, and I can't find a Linux debugger of any kind.

Comment: It'd be great if you'd verify your answer before posting - I talked to NVidia earlier and they confirmed that there's no way to connect VS to a Linux box for debugging.

Comment: The line starts with : As far as I remember. Sorry to be human and thanks to verify the affirmation. I updated the answer with another way to do it.

Comment: It's not personal; even starting an answer with "As far as I remember..." isn't an excuse for a blatantly incorrect answer. A lot of us *delete* answers that we posted if they are factually incorrect, as this is. Your update addresses this, but still doesn't provide an answer to the question.

Comment: I will leave it there, thanks to your update, my answer would be useful to many other people that would ask your same question.