# Returning incorrect number while adding in CUDA

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I am trying to follow a tutorial I found [online](http://www.math.uaa.alaska.edu/~afkjm/cs448/handouts/cuda-firstprograms.pdf). I am using Ubuntu 17, compiling from the command line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

__global__ void add(int a, int b, int *c)
{
    *c = a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    int *d_c;
    int size = sizeof(int);

    a = 2;
    b = 7;

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c,size;
    add<<<1,1>>>(a,b,d_c);
    cudaMemcpy(&c,d_c,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    std::cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << std::endl;
    cudaFree(d_c);

    return 0;
 }
```

When I compile with `nvcc` I get the following error:

`nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).`

I ignored the warning and ran `a.out` as usual, and I get the output:

`2 + 7 = 1`

Last time I did maths, this is incorrect. I am not sure if I am doing this incorrectly, or if the tutorial I am following is too old, or if it has something to do with the warning? Any help or leads will do. I will also mention, that I was not able to compile with `nvcc` until I installed `gcc-5`. I believe I have linked them together correctly by using [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622454/cuda-incompatible-with-my-gcc-version) I found here.

I have also looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473495/cuda-c-why-is-it-not-printing-out-the-value-copied-from-device-memory) here as well. However, I did not find the answer particularly helpful so I would appreciate some insight if this is compiling correctly, why this is not printing out correctly to my terminal.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to [`cudaMemcpy()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc263dbe6574220cc776b45438fc351e8) is incorrect. You should copy the result from the device (GPU) memory  to host (CPU) memory, not other way around. The correct `kind` flag to use is `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost` :

```
cudaMemcpy(&c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

In order to simplify the debugging in the future, think about implementing [proper CUDA API error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) as well as systematically running your programs with [`cuda-memcheck`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html), [`cuda-gdb`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-gdb/index.html), valgrind and clang sanitizers.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I have updated my code to use `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost` and I still get the result of 1. Let me try the error checking, I took a peak at that thread a couple of times but never thought to try and implement it.

Comment: Just found out my error, thank you so much for leading me to error checking. GPU Assert returned, `no CUDA-capable device is detected hello.cu 29` I will go ahead and work out why this is happening.

Comment: It is great that you have implemented the error checking right away. Sometimes it takes a while to convince people here to do that. So, what error message says is: your kernel function is not even executed, because CUDA runtime cannot find a CUDA-capable device. Make sure that you have a recent Nvidia card (Fermi and above, [one of these](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) with Compute Capability >= 2.0) and that the [driver is properly installed](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html). After sorting these out, the fixed code should work.

Comment: Thank you again, yeah I have a 1080ti installed and it is compatible. I am not sure what I did in order to get the drivers all mixed up. But I have begun a journey down a dark hole where I found when I run `nvidia-smi` I get the message `Driver/Library version mismatch`. So I am at the point of trying to sort that out. I believe error checking is the best tool to implement in anything, I am a huge believer in debugging as well.